# How to make a discord bot store/find the rest of a message after a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

What I'm trying to do is work out how to make the bot check what's after the initial command.

i.e:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

@bot.command(name="suggestion")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx):
      (code to find what came after suggestion)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.args` should give you a List of arguments passed towards the command.

`ctx.content` will also give you all the content of the message, if that's what you want.

Alternatively, you can also do something like this:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

@bot.command(name="suggestion")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx, suggestion_name, content):
      print(suggestion_name, content)
```

You invoke it like this:
`/suggestion feature "I want a new feature!"`

`discord.py` will automatically parse text in a quote as a single argument. You can do stuff like:

`/suggestion "Add an image command" "I think an image command would be cool"`

Comment: Um, I have never used arguments or the ctx function before so have usually avoided them. There's no time like the present, how do arguments work?

Comment: In my example, if you invoke with `/suggestion apple "more apples"` then in the function the following is true, `suggestion_name == "apple"` & `content == "more apples"`

Comment: Thank you, I think i understand

Comment: @Tazgirl If this resolved the problem you may mark it as the answer. If not, please lmk. I'll be happy to elaborate over anything.